# sed not working within $()

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace part of the filename with sed during a move.  What I want is to make evident that certain file goes from "READY" to "SENT" just after a transfer operation:

Assuming two files (at least), that for test purposes I'm generating with touch:

```
>touch READY01_file_to_process.txt
>touch READY02_file_to_process.txt
```

Then I'm trying to do this:

```
>ls READY* | xargs -I% mv "%" $(echo "%" | sed 's/READY/SENT/')
```

But it doesn't work as expected.  Just to debug it I changed 'mv' into 'echo' like this:

```
>ls READY* | xargs -I% echo "%" $(echo "%" | sed 's/READY/SENT/')
```

I'm expecting to see this output:

```
READY01_file_to_process.txt SENT01_file_to_process.txt
READY02_file_to_process.txt SENT02_file_to_process.txt
```

But it gives the following instead (no substitution at all):

```
READY01_file_to_process.txt READY01_file_to_process.txt
READY02_file_to_process.txt READY02_file_to_process.txt
```

I'm pretty sure it's something stupid I just can't spot... 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and there are other ways to rename files

1) If you have `rename` command not based on `perl`, something like this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

```
$ touch READY0{1,2}_file_to_process.txt
$ # -v is for verbose output
$ # note how same glob is used as what you used with ls
$ rename -v READY SENT READY*
`READY01_file_to_process.txt' -> `SENT01_file_to_process.txt'
`READY02_file_to_process.txt' -> `SENT02_file_to_process.txt'
```

2) If you have `perl` based `rename`

```
$ # -n is for dry run, remove and run cmd again after it looks okay
$ rename -n 's/READY/SENT/' READY*
rename(READY01_file_to_process.txt, SENT01_file_to_process.txt)
rename(READY02_file_to_process.txt, SENT02_file_to_process.txt)
```

3) for-loop and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion

```
$ # remove echo once it looks okay
$ for f in READY*; do echo mv "$f" "${f/READY/SENT}"; done
mv READY01_file_to_process.txt SENT01_file_to_process.txt
mv READY02_file_to_process.txt SENT02_file_to_process.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll probably choose solution 3).